# Adrian-Marie’s Theory of Numbers Book

Tags: euclidean-geometry

Recently I have found out about this famous book from the french mathematician Adrian-Marie called the theory of numbers, I think citing eculidians elements. I really want to read this book but don’t know where to find it since any copy on the internet is worth over 3 grand. Does anyone know where I will find this book?

Comment: Presumably you refer to A. M. Legendre's [Essai sur la Théorie des Nombres](https://www.maa.org/press/periodicals/convergence/mathematical-treasure-legendre-on-number-theory). As mentioned there it is [online at ECHO.](http://echo.mpiwg-berlin.mpg.de/ECHOdocuView?url=/mpiwg/online/permanent/library/9YTT35D8/pageimg&viewMode=index&mode=imagepath) $\ \ $

Comment: Thank you very much not sure why this got downvoted I thought it was a fairly reasonable question

Comment: Possibly because you could easily obtain the answer by searching on "Adrian-Marie Theory of Numbers" (sic). That's merely a guess (I didn't downvote).

Comment: The book is also available from [Linda Hall Library Digital Editions](http://lhldigital.lindahall.org/cdm/ref/collection/math/id/31581)